# Windows api get client dc bitmap size

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, mfc

I use the following code to get the size of the bitmap bound with Windows MFC View window's client area DC:

```
void CView::OnDraw(CDC* )
{
    CDC *pDc = GetDC();
    BITMAP bmpHeader;
    memset( &bmpHeader, 0, sizeof(BITMAP));
    HGDIOBJ hbmp = GetCurrentObject(pDc->m_hDC, OBJ_BITMAP);
    GetObject(hbmp,sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpHeader);

    int bmpWidth = bmpHeader.bmWidth;
    int bmpHeight = bmpHeader.bmHeight;
    ...
}
```

According to MSDN GetDC() gets the client area dc:

> Retrieves a pointer to a common, class, or private device context for the client area depending on the class style specified for the CWnd

So I suppose the *bmpWidth* and *bmpHeight* should be the same size as client area rect. But it isn't. It appears to be the size of entire window including toolbar area and menu area. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GetClientRect` to find with and height of client area. This is the area which does not include the titlebar and borders. Instead of calling `GetDC()`, use the `CDC*` parameter which is already provided, or else use `CClientDC dc(this)` which has automatic cleanup. In this case drawing should be something like this:

```
void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* dc)
{
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc); 
    dc->FillSolidRect(rc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
}
```

Use [Window Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get information about Windows.

Most Window functions have equivalent in MFC. For example,

In WinApi: `GetClientRect(HWND hwnd, LPRECT rc);`

In MFC: `CWnd::GetClientRect(LPRECT rc);`